# Raspberry Pi's and Server Fault

Tags: discussion

Are questions regarding the Raspberry Pi platform topical on Server fault?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the vast majority of cases the answer is NO. There will be a vanishingly small number of use case where Server Fault would (knowingly) accept questions about the Raspberry Pi platform.

For reference I present our discussion: https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/5586/are-raspberrypis-ever-on-topic-for-serverfault and our [about](https://serverfault.com/about).

We actively close *all* RPi related questions that we get as off topic

> "**Questions must be relevant to [professional](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/4111/what-is-a-professional-capacity) system administration**. Server Fault is dedicated to professional system and network administrators. End user and enthusiast questions are off-topic (contact your system administrator or hire a professional to help you out). Please see the [Help Center](https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) for more information."

and point people at this site.

If you have questions which are RPi related and which do not fit into *your* scope then in general [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [Super User](https://superuser.com/)  are much better suited to the entusiast nature of this platform.

Comment: I did not know this! Thanks Iain.

Comment: It gets very hard lately to find out and follow where a specific question on the Stackexchange network belongs to, especially when it comes to problems that almost fit everywhere.